# Java scrollPane added on runtime won't scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

[image: The GUI we're building]
We are trying to make an application which contains multiple scrollpanes. The first one works more or less fine. We can't resize the panel which it has to scroll on runtime. So to fix this problem we set the size in the GUI builder:

[image: The hacky fix]

Only with this hacky fix the panel to scroll takes it correct size. Because the code wouldn't work:

```
    PanelGraph.setPreferredSize(PanelGraph.getPreferredSize());
    PanelGraph.validate();
    TopPanel.setSize(locationX, (panelDatabase.length * 15));
    TopPanel.setPreferredSize(TopPanel.getPreferredSize());
    TopPanel.validate();
    TopScrollPanel.setViewportView(TopPanel);
    TopScrollPanel.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(15);
    TopScrollPanel.validate();
```

The TopPanel is the Panel which is in the TopScrollPanel and we tried to set the size with the length of the history array times the pixels of one row (15). This code won't resize the TopPanel or the viewportview. This part works for now, but we're still wondering how we could fix this?

For the second scrollPanel we have to resize it everytime we update the panel, because the list grows. Whatever code we're trying to use: the scrollpane won't scroll. When we click this function is called:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    history = SensorValuesHistory();
    javax.swing.JScrollPane HistoryLogPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    HistoryLogPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout()); // edit @kiheru
    HistoryLogPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    HistoryLogPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    HistoryLogPane.setLocation(0, 0);
    HistoryLogPane.add(history);
    HistoryLogPane.setSize(new Dimension(history.getSize()));
    history.setPreferredSize(history.getSize());//and we tried: history.setPreferredSize(history.getPreferredSize());
    System.out.println("SIZE: " + HistoryLogPane.getSize());
    HistoryLocationPanel.removeAll();
    HistoryLocationPanel.add(HistoryLogPane);
    HistoryLocationPanel.repaint();
    HistoryLogPane.repaint();
}
```

Because of the first problem, we remove the old scrollpane and generate a new one. What do we have to do te let this scrollPane scroll?

Comment: question in this form is too hard to be answerable here (without an SSCCE/MCVE, and with printscreen from some GUI Buider, that by default complicating very simple things), read Oracle tutorial about How to use Scrollpanes, for working code example in SSCCE/MCVE form

Comment: with success with revalidate + repaint to the (one, and closest parent) container

Comment: playing with setPreferredSize isn't correct way (as you can to see in your case), even is possible but, but required the basics from algebra (playing with pixels perfections for un_knows LayoutManager == various LayoutManager differently accepts PreferredSize)

Comment: `JScrollPane` shows the scroll bars when the preferred size of the contained component is large enough. Determining the preferred size is normally the job of the layout manager. Just use one, as that's the way swing is designed to be used. The root of the problem is using `null` layouts.

Comment: Also, you should set the view of a `JScrollPane`, not `add()` components to it.

Comment: @mKorbel, we know that the code isn't what it has to be, we are trying to find a way to make it work properly but we simply don't know how.

Comment: @kiheru, we tried the adjustments, but now the HistoryLogPane isn't showing at all. The function addView doesn't exist and the addViewPortView doesn't seem to work...?

Comment: The simplest is using a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane%28java.awt.Component%29) that takes the view as a parameter, but `setViewportView()` should work as well - and you apparently already use it for the other panel.  I did not mean explicitly using `ScrollPaneLayout` - that's what the scroll pane itself uses, but an ordinary layout managed for the *contained component*, which if I read correctly is `history`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kiheru, thanks for the suggestions and directions! By revalidating the history panel instead of the scrollpane the functions works fine now! This is the working code:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    HistoryLogPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());//<<<
    history = (JPanel)HistoryLogPane.getViewport().getView();//<<<
    javax.swing.JScrollPane HistoryLogPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    HistoryLogPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout()); // edit @kiheru
    HistoryLogPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    HistoryLogPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    HistoryLogPane.setLocation(0, 0);
    HistoryLogPane.add(history);
    HistoryLogPane.setSize(new Dimension(history.getSize()));
    history.setPreferredSize(history.getSize());//and we tried: history.setPreferredSize(history.getPreferredSize());
    history.revalidate();//<<<
    System.out.println("SIZE: " + HistoryLogPane.getSize());
    HistoryLocationPanel.removeAll();
    HistoryLocationPanel.add(HistoryLogPane);
    HistoryLocationPanel.repaint();
    HistoryLogPane.repaint();
}
```

after each row we've added we've put a '//<<<' to point it out.